# Discussion forums for HEP theory?

Tags: resource-recommendations, standard-model, education

This forum works well for its intended purpose of asking and answering factual questions, but doesn't provide an avenue for more open ended discussion of HEP theory topics for a self-selected group of informed and interested individuals. Are there any such forms available publicly?  Google has not been useful, and the blogs I've sampled don't quite fit that description either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of anything that feels comparable to the glory days of the old sci.physics.research USENET group.  There is physicsforums.org, but it doesn't have the same feel.  The pace of conversation is glacial.  You're better off just going where-ever Baez & Schreiber are hanging out these days.  But you've said you've sampled the physics blogs, and that they aren't really what you're looking for.

I'm not sure such forums really could operate publicly (or at least not prominently).  Most professionals don't have the time or patience to put up with the cranks that overrun such forums.   Cranks can be dealt with, but that's not a trivial effort.  The best discussions I've seen lately have actually been on Facebook, but that's not particularly accessible.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I feared as much from what I've found.  Your info is helpful in confirming that I haven't missed something obvious.  Even some of the regular bloggers of recent years seem to have pulled back lately altho Baez still seems fairly active as you note.  Sad, and an impediment to progress IMHO.  Exchange of ideas is so critical.

Comment: @JimEshelman Sorry I don't have a better answer!